# How can I run Monero CLI commands through a JS script or in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

React Native does not support child process Node.js modules. So, how can I run all Monero CLI functions through native code in React Native?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in React Native. The monero cli requires both `monero-wallet-cli` and `monerod` to be running, and you cannot spawn a separate server-style process in React Native.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run node in react native, it is not the same environment. Node JS operates generally on servers.

Monero CLI is working with monero daemon and you can't have neither of these running in your react-native environement, a potential solution to your problem will be to run a monero daemon on a server and monero wallet cli and your react-native app making requests to your server to make changes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).